# Fatal error: Class '2' not found in

Tags: php, sql, class

I am getting two columns from llamadas where idLlamadas is the primary key, I want to get these values so I can use them later but when I try to use the primary key on $v ... I am getting this error: `Fatal error: Class '2' not found in ...` I did some tests and it looks like the '2' is a value in idLlamadas, it gives me the same error if it is 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. it conflicts with the first value.

***code:***

```
$q = ("SELECT idLlamadas, comentarios FROM llamadas");
$sql = mysqli_query($con, $q);

foreach ($sql->fetch_all() as $k => $v){

    var_dump ($k);
    var_dump ($v);

    $comentario = $v(0);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `use the primary key on $v `?

Comment: it might not be important but ... idLlamadas is the primary key of table (llamadas) ... and when i try to use it as $v(0) ... is when i am getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're accessing this data, `$v` should be an array containing [idLlamadas, comentarios] for each iteration. You're currently trying to execute it like a function or class constructor, which will cause PHP to fail as it is currently.

However, `mysqli_result->fetch_all()` is a very resource hungry way of retrieving data from the database. I recommend you restructure your code as follows:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `idLlamadas`, `comentarios` FROM `llamadas`';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        var_dump($row); // outputs array('idLlamadas' => 1, 'comentarios' => 'No somos tortugas.')
        // You can get the id with $row['idLlamadas']
        // Or the comment with $row['comentarios']
    }
} else {
    print('MySQLi error: [' . mysqli_errno($con) . '] ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: I must be tired now :), i see my mistake and also ... thank you for the advise on mysqli_result->fetch_all() that might resolve another issue I am having

Comment: De nada. :) Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `$comentario = $v(0);`.

`$v` is an array, and if you want to get the value of `idLlamadas`, then use `$v[0]` but not `$v(0)`.